# Azure ARM Template Deployment: Authoriztion issue

Tags: azure

I am trying to deployment following [template](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_CreateUIDef/CustomDeploymentBlade/uri/https%3A%2F%2Fraw.githubusercontent.com%2FAzure%2FEnterprise-Scale%2Fmain%2Fdocs%2Freference%2Fadventureworks%2FarmTemplates%2Fes-hubspoke.json/createUIDefinitionUri/https%3A%2F%2Fraw.githubusercontent.com%2FAzure%2FEnterprise-Scale%2Fmain%2Fdocs%2Freference%2Fadventureworks%2FarmTemplates%2Fportal-es-hubspoke.json)

Although I elevated the access rights of the client to manage all resources of all subscriptions I keep getting following error:

The client 'xxxxxxxx' with object id 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Resources/deployments/validate/action' over scope '/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/NoMarketplace-20201007104429' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.

Any helpful input to solve this issue is welcome.
Thx!

Answer (score 0):

means you didnt actually elevate the access or the user didnt relogin after you did.

Comment: By performing  "az role assignment list --role "User Access Administrator" --scope "/""  I can see that the user has "User access Administrator" role. Is that not sufficient? Thx

Comment: no, its not. this role doesnt give permissions, it only gives permissions to assign permissions